# He felt torn between/among his family and his friends

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, between-among

*Among* is used when we see a group of three or more people or things.
*Between* is used when we see two or more people or things as separate individuals.

Which preposition do we use if there is more than one group of things or people?

For example:

- He felt torn between/among his family and his friends.
- there was a sense of unease between/among the students and teachers.
- There was a conflict between/among the universities of Leeds, York, and Manchester.

Comment: I am not familiar with your definitions of *among* and *between*.  You should find these words in a dictionary and edit your question to reflect the definitions you find there.

Comment: I would be happy to but prepositions have many definitions in English and it may be helpful to be familiar with some of them for these two words.

Comment: 'Between' seems right for the first and last, but less clear for the middle one, lacking context.

Answer (score 5):

In idiomatic BrE it's always **torn between**. Something (an idea, a suspicion, a loyalty etc) is pulling you in two or more different directions hence **torn**. You are conflicted.
Again, it is usual to say "... sense of unease **among** the students ..." since it is a shared feeling not a conflict.
The third example is a conflict, so **between** is probably the best.
But again the universities share this conflict among them.
So, in general, something that divides is **between** and something that is shared is **among**.

Comment: It's the same in AmE.

Comment: I'd add that "family and friends" are 2 groups divided, and "There was a sense of unease between the students and teachers" seems the same, no matter how many were within each group. The friction lay in the conflict that students and teachers had with each other, not that the whole school was in conflict. Though that could be meant, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right starting point: "between" is for two things, "among" is for more. "Keep this secret just **between** us" but "We share the pie **among** the three of us."

The thing about groups is that they can be treated in singular *or* plural. We can talk about the group as a whole, or about its members. So the above rule holds; we just have to figure out how many entities we're talking about.

- *There was a fierce battle **between** the English army and the French army.* There were many people, but we're consolidating them into just two parties.
- *There was discontent **among** the English army.* Now we're talking about plural people. Now here's where it could go either way:
- *There was tension [**between/among**] the English and French armies.* If we choose "between," we're talking about the tension of one army against another; if we choose "among," we mean that all those soldiers from both armies experienced some tension.

So your "sense of unease" example could go either way depending on your intent.